# How to get Butterknife working?

Tags: android, butterknife

I am using Butterknife for my android project. I have previously used this, but for some reason it no longer works with the new update.

Here is my setup:

(App Module) **build.gradle**:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
```

**activity**:

```
@BindView(R.id.navigation_pager) ViewPager mViewPager;

/.../

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /...
    /...
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

**stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

What am I missing in order to get `Butterknife` working?

Thanks.

Comment: did you add the apt dependency

Comment: Just clean your project when you make changes in xml as Butterknife stores static references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

in Project gradle file

And Add:

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

and this at top:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

for butterknife to work

For more info refer this link:https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Answer (score 1):

Configure your project-level build.gradle to include the 'android-apt' plugin:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}
```

Then, apply the 'android-apt' plugin in your module-level build.gradle and add the Butter Knife dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

.`

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @BindView(R.id.navigation_pager) ViewPager mViewPager;
      @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
      viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));
    }
}

**MAKE SURE TO CALL setAdapter() only after ButterKnife.bind(this);**
```